# Решение тригонометрического уравнения sympy

Tags: python-3.5, sympy

Необходимо решить тригонометрическое уравнение на Python в Sympy. Сейчас делаю так:

```
import sympy
from  sympy.abc import *

exp = 'cos( x)**2 + sin( x) * cos( x) - 1'
ans = sympy.solve(exp, x)
print(ans)
```

Вывод:

```
[0, -3*pi/4, pi/4]
```

Но мне необходимо получить ответы, как на картинке:
[image: Ответ]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: ну обычно в тригонометрии ответ ищется только на промежутке длиной в 2PI (после приведения)... добавить период обычно проблемы нет

Comment: А не могли бы вы сказать, как так сделать?